# Need to receive a custom intent from shortcuts.xml to invoke a custom method in the activity

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

Hey I've been trying to receive a custom intent in InComingShortcuts.java

```
public class InComingShortcuts extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences setting = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    String TAG="PocketModeService";
    if(intent.getAction().equals("com.rituj.theoneplus3app.gestures")){
        Log.d(TAG, "Got gestures Broadcast");
    }
}}
```

From this shortcuts.xml:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_gestures"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/static_shortcut_disabled_message"
        android:shortcutId="static"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/static_shortcut_long_label"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/static_shortcut_short_label">
        <intent
            android:action="com.rituj.theoneplus3app.gestures"/>
    </shortcut>

</shortcuts>
```

and AndroidManifest look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packagename">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="App LAbel"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeLight">

        <receiver
            android:name="com.rituj.theoneplus3app.InComingShortcuts"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.rituj.theoneplus3app.gestures" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="Label"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLight"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

           <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts" android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I'm trying to implement the android Nougat 7.1.1 app shortcuts.
It just doesn't receive any intent by that name.
Any help would be appreciated.
 I need to invoke a particular method to inflate a different layout if  the user pressed that shortcut. How do I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below in my app, you can change it accordingly, in your `shortcut` xmlm specify `intent` like this.

```
        <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:data="some data"
        android:targetPackage="com.x.y.z.debug"
        android:targetClass="com.x.y.z.XYZActivity" />
```

Notice `com.x.y.z` could ends with 'debug' if running as debug build

Comment: But this would start the main activity, right? I need to invoke a particular method to inflate a different layout if  the user pressed that shortcut. How do I do this.

Comment: You can handle that intent in `XYZActivity` right? based on the data parsed in, you can call any method you want